# seaborn mislabel of lineplots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The lines plotted using `seaborn.lineplot` with the hue set to differentiate the data mislabels the range of the variable 'VG', while using the style to differentiate the range does not mislabel the range of VG.

**Minimal example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
fig,axes=plt.subplots(nrows=2)
sns.lineplot(x="VDS", y="ID", hue="VG",data=df,ax=axes[0])
sns.lineplot(x="VDS", y="ID", style="VG",data=df,ax=axes[1])
```

using this [test data](https://gist.github.com/leobrowning92/1728496f89f67aa8c829df6cd437c365).

gives the output:

[image]

even though the actual range of values for `VG` is -20 to 20.

I would firstly like to a) fix this in this case b) find out if I should log an issue with the seaborn(or pandas?) github.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Cheers

Comment: The API documentation specifies that "[hue] can be either categorical or numeric, although color mapping will behave differently in latter case." Therefore it looks like there is something specific about having a numerical `hue`, but I don't know exactly how. On simple way to fix the problem in the meantime would be to add a categorical column to your DataFrame (e.g. [using `pandas.cut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.cut.html))